# Aligning two blocks in CS-Cart v4.03

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS to keep my header fixed while scrolling. When I make this change it throws off the header and I cannot keep it centered.

CSS:

```
.tygh-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 950px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -485px;
}
.tygh-content {
    padding-top: 119px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here is what the site looks like without the Fixed position.
http://puu.sh/5SK5Y.jpg

Here is the site after loading the CSS.
http://puu.sh/5SK6O.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to set for its parent:

```
Position:relative
```

and  use for your header:

```
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
height:120px;
```

Comment: I add this yet it stills pushes the header way to far to the right and it does not move with browser resizing.

Comment: I change width to relative width,please use width:100%

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you Saeed Py. Now if only I could figure out java, I could have only the menu float and not the whole header. Thanks!